# UICollectionView doesn't bounce when datasource has only 1 item

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uiscrollviewdelegate, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView with a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout. It scrolls horizontally and only shows one item at a time (full height). I have pagingEnabled = YES so that it sticks to pages.

The UICollectionView shows photos within a particular day. I initially had buttons to change the day +/- 1 day, but I thought it would be neat if the user could pull on the collection view past the first or last image (past a predetermined threshold) to change the day. I implemented this using the UIScrollView delegate methods and it works great...... if there are 2 or more items in the collection view.

This is hard to describe, but if there is only 1 item, it doesn't allow me to pull the item past it's bounds. I.E. there is no bounce to it.

I'd like to have this behavior, but I need to overcome this problem first. I'm thinking that if I removed pagingEnabled = YES and used targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:proposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity, that I may be able to get it to work but I really enjoy the snappy behavior that paging enables. (They are mutually exclusive).

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

`UICollectionView` has the properties `alwaysBounceHorizontal` and `alwaysBounceVertical`. Setting the horizontal to YES `did` the trick.

Comment: To enable this inside the Interface Builder — use the option called "Bounce Vertically".

Comment: `alwaysBounceHorizontal` and  `alwaysBounceVertical` are originated from view `UIScrollView`.

Comment: So can I say that `UITableView` has this property set to `YES` as default since it can be bounds?

Comment: For me assigning *layout* instance in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` was the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for @VaporwareWolf ,the answer is correct. I want to add a supplement that:

> DO NOT forget setting the `bounces` property to `YES` at the same time（through storyboard or your code）.