# Custom viewcontroller container (similar to UIPageViewController), but with no scrolling bounce

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

Using UIPageViewController as container is pretty straightforward, however, it is extremely hacky to disable its bounce effect. I need help on creating a custom container ViewController (similar to UIPageVC) using UIScrollView and ViewController containment API. Is there any existing repo on github?

thx

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use UICollectionView. You can set up it without bouncing. You can do it with setting alwaysBounceVertical and alwaysBounceHorisontal properties. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069357/uicollectionview-does-not-scroll) and [here](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-collection-views-using-flow-layout/) about it. Also UICollectionView is very easy to use and customize. I don't think you need use some external libs or repos.

Comment: I guess you misunderstand my question or i interpret it inaccurately. The thing im looking for is a custom container (similar to UIPageViewController) that manages array of child controllers.