# UICollectionView can't scroll down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

i have uicollectionview in a view controller.
i have 
HomeCell it's UICollectionViewCell 
and my UIView Controller is HomeController,
but when i run my apps, the collection view cell doesn't scroll.

can you help me, im a new in using Objective-C language.

here's my HomeController.h code :

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return arrayOfLyrics.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Lyrics *lyric = [[Lyrics alloc]init];
    lyric = [arrayOfLyrics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    CellHome *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellHome" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.myTitle.text = lyric.title;
    cell.myArtis.text = lyric.artis;
    [cell.myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:lyric.image]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    _passLyric = [arrayOfLyrics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailView" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Can you check if the following properties are set for your `UICollectionView` : `userInteractionEnabled`, `scrollEnabled`, `bounces` and `alwaysBounceVertical`.

Comment: Also, answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069357/uicollectionview-does-not-scroll) may be of help.

Comment: where to add bounces ?? 
HomeController.h or HomeController.m or HomeCell.m ?

Comment: You'll want to set this in *HomeController.m*'s `viewDidLoad` method or any other place where you are setting up your `UICollectionView`

Comment: have you set delegates and datasource of UICollectionView?

Comment: yes.. i have set it in HomeController.h ..

Comment: How have your set the UICollectionViewFlowLayout? Please post all initialization code.